# How to slice a 2-D Java array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

folks,

I am working with JTables and have a 2-D array. I need to remove the first element of every row in the array. Is there a simpler way to do it besides?

```
int height = data2.length;
int width = data2[0].length;
Object[][] data = new Object[height][width];
for (int j=0; j<height; j++) {
    for (int i=1; i<width; i++) {
        data[j][i-1] = data2[j][i];
    }
}
data2 = data;
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Wouldn't it be a whole lot easier to ... not use arrays? According to the JavaDocs you can use `Vector`s instead. Or create your own model that uses any Collection type you'd like.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am using arrays as an intermediary storage going from JSON to table data. JTable is constrained to Object[][] type arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you can use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) instead of the inner loop:

```
Object[][] data = new Object[height][width];
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    System.arraycopy(data2[i], 1, data[i], 0, width-1);
}
```