# Java slicing multidimensional array library

Tags: java, arrays, slice

Is there a Java array library which supports slicing? I just need regular **n x n' x n'' x ...** arrays and either taking one slice from given dimension or whole dimension (i.e. no need for ranges).

Notes (read replies to potential comments):

- I know that regular Java arrays are not supporting it and I'm not willing to write my own slicing library.
- Using `Collection` (suggested in comment to [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898504/how-to-slice-a-2-d-java-array)) based shifts the problem
- Using [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) does not help in high dimension as it does not lower the nesting of loops significantly
- This is (sort of - long story) numerical problem so OO approach for inner code is not necessary the best one - the most usable abstraction boils down to slicing anyway
- I would prefer R/W view from slice (if it will only be R/O copy I won't complain though)

**EDIT:** Unfortunaly I need to store objects inside array - not only `double`'s.

Comment: maybe you are using the wrong tool(java) for the job? Alternatively, would a map with each dimension as a key work?

Comment: @drone.ah: It's long story but based on description it is what I would say as well.

Answer (score 5):

[Vectorz](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz) is a vector/matrix library supports slicing and is a good choice if you are doing numerical work with arrays of `double` values. It is specifically designed for vector/matrix maths in 3D modelling, gaining, simulation or machine learning contexts.

Advantages:

- Very fast (everything backed by primitive `double`s and `double[]` arrays)
- 100% Pure Java
- Supports arbitrary slicing and dicing, mostly as `O(1)` operations (i.e. no data copying required)
- Slices are fully read/write enabled, i.e. you can use them to modify the original structures
- You can also join vectors together, take subvector views etc.
- Specialised classes for numerical work, e.g. diagonal matrices etc.

It currently supports 0, 1 and 2 dimensional arrays, higher dimensional arrays are planned but not yet implemented.

Comment: +1. Looks nice however I need something to store an object inside array - not only `double` (I admit - I might mislead by using 'numerical' inside description).

Comment: Nice library. It seems to be modeled after `numpy` arrays.  V fast, but does not have many features.